# Chained comparison in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>> k
array([[0.58789735, 0.29830086],
       [0.09397728, 0.60737265]])
>>> k[k<0.1] = 1
>>> k[k>0.5] = 1
>>> k
array([[1.        , 0.29830086],
       [1.        , 1.        ]])
```

Is it possible to combine k[0.1>K>0.5] = 1, when I try to do something like that, I get following error

```
>>> k[0.1>k>0.5] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What are my options here? I tried with .any and .all, it is not as elegant as what I am trying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chained comparisons are not allowed in numpy. You need to chain those conditions with [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and then perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). In this case you want to set a value to `1` when either condition is satisfied, so you need an bitwise OR (`|`):

```
k = np.array([[0.58789735, 0.29830086],
              [0.09397728, 0.60737265]])

k[(k<0.1)|(k>.5)] = 1

print(k)
[[1.         0.29830086]
 [1.         1.        ]]
```

---

It was actually proposed to make this possible in [PEP 535](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/), though it still remains deferred. In it there is an explanation on why this occurs. As posed in the question, chaining comparisons in such way, yields:

```
0.1>k>0.5
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()

The problem here, is that python is internally expanding the above to:

```
0.1>k and k>0.5
```

Which is what causes the error, since `and` is implicitly calling `bool`, and `NumPy` only permits implicit coercion to a boolean value for single elements (not arrays with `size>1`), since a boolean array with many values does not evaluate neither to `True` or `False`. It is due to this ambiguity that this isn't allowed, and evaluating an array in boolean context always yields a `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

Run `np.where(np.logical_or(k < 0.1, 0.5 < k), 1, k)`.

The result is:

```
array([[1.        , 0.29830086],
       [1.        , 1.        ]])
```